# How can loop a series and add to the values multiple times to a new list?

Tags: python, list, append, series

I have a Series like below

```
import pandas as pd 
a = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

I want to loop this Series and append to the new list and my expected result like that

```
new_lst = [a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,d,e,e,e,e,e]
```

This is I tried before

```
new_lst = []
for i in a:
    new_lst.append(i*5)
```

but i got the result bolow

```
['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd', 'eeeee']
```

Comment: use `extend` instead of `append`

Comment: you're adding a character 5 times instead of an element 5 times. You can `new_lst += [i] *5`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> list(a.repeat(5))
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Comment: thx orlp,i tried and got my expected already

Answer (score 1):

`i` in your `for` loop is a `str` object. When you multiply a `str` with a `int`, you repeat the `str` a number of times. In your case, `i*5` repeats string `i` 5 times.

An easy solution is to simply append the string 5 times. For example,

```
new_lst = []
for i in a:
    new_lst.append(i)
    new_lst.append(i)
    new_lst.append(i)
    new_lst.append(i)
    new_lst.append(i)
```

Simply appends the object 5 times.

If you want a better looking solution, you can repeat the `append` statement 5 times with another `for` loop:

```
new_lst = []
for i in a:
    for j in range(5):
        new_lst.append(i)
```